# the openresty new certificate did not work

Tags: https, ssl-certificate

I have renewed the certificate on the server side, but the website always told that the ssl certificate are not secure. I have tried to restart&reload the openresty like this:

```
[root@k8sslave01 source]# /usr/local/openresty/bin/openresty -s reload
```

and this is how I start the openresty:

```
/usr/local/openresty/bin/openresty -c /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
```

make sure the new certificate are not expired using this command:

```
[root@k8sslave01 source]# /usr/bin/openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/poemhub/fullchain.pem  -checkend "$DAYS"
notAfter=Apr 30 23:59:59 2024 GMT
```

this is the nginx config look like:

```
[root@k8sslave01 conf.d]# cat tex.poemhub.top-443.conf
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  tex.poemhub.top;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/poemhub/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/poemhub/privkey.pem;

    if ($allowed = 0) {
        return 403;
    }

    location / {
        client_max_body_size 1m;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_read_timeout 3600;
        proxy_pass http://172.29.217.209:8000;
    }

    location /tex/project/log/stream {
        proxy_cache off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_read_timeout 3600;
        proxy_pass http://172.29.217.209:8000;
    }

    location /tex/project/compile/qlog {
        proxy_cache off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_read_timeout 3600;
        proxy_pass http://172.29.217.209:8000;
    }

    location /tex/static/proj {
        alias /data/k8s/reddwarf-pro/texhub-server-service/project/;
        autoindex off;
    }

    location /tex/static/tpl {
        alias /data/k8s/reddwarf-pro/texhub-server-service/template/;
        autoindex off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which clients do show the SSL error message? Have you tested the SSL/TLS configuration of your server using e.g. test tools like https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest?